PC can't route to a Hyper-V Virtual machine and vice versa

Status


My PC has a Hyper-V VM and a WSL instance, which IP addrs are 192.168.254.30 and 192.168.254.20, respectively.
The goal is to establish a TCP connection from the WSL to the Hyper-V VM, but the PC cannot route to the VM.


WSL instance

#ifconfig

...

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.50.39  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.63.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe91:7e17  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:91:7e:17  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 80470  bytes 119447117 (119.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13016  bytes 1130767 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.254.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255
        ether 00:15:5d:91:7e:17  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

...


Hyper-V

Ethernet adapter Default:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mshome.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::aca0:3022:c8b1:fef%17
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.127.44
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.19.112.1

Ethernet adapter WSL:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::24f7:b664:6f15:ccf%27
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.48.30
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.40
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.100
                                       192.168.48.1


tracert from the PC

> tracert 192.168.254.20

최대 30홉 이상의 192.168.254.20(으)로 가는 경로 추적

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.254.20

추적을 완료했습니다. #Tracing done.

> tracert 192.168.254.30

최대 30홉 이상의 192.168.254.30(으)로 가는 경로 추적

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  172.25.18.2
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  172.25.255.153
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  172.28.255.49
...


The route table in the PC

IPv4 route table
===========================================================================
active routes:
network target      network mask    gateway      interface    metric
...
    192.168.254.0    255.255.255.0  connected      192.168.48.1   5256
...


ipconfig setting in the VM

Ethernet adapter WSL:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::24f7:b664:6f15:ccf%27
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.48.30
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.40
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.100
                                       192.168.48.1

The weird thing is that, unused addresses in 192.168.254.0/24 are routed to 192.168.254.100.
> tracert 192.168.254.50    <----- no server is using this

최대 30홉 이상의 192.168.254.50(으)로 가는 경로 추적

  1  john-doe-pc [192.168.254.100]  report: cannot connect to the host.

tracing done.

And if I change the IP addr of the Hyper-V VM to this 192.168.254.50, the PC starts to route this 192.168.254.50 via 172.25.18.2, which is the route to the internet. Do I have to do something in the VM?

What type of virtual adapter was created in Hyper-V Manager? The Default virtual adapter in Hyper-V can't be used for routing anything other than WAN traffic for Hyper-V VMs
